# Jest runs tests in node_modules after update to Angular 13

Tags: angular, jestjs

After updating Angular to Version 13 the jest-runner runs tests in the node_module. For instance:

```
Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'chai' from 'node_modules_/@compodoc/compodoc/src/app/compiler/deps/helpers/symbol-helper.spec.ts'

  1 | import { SymbolHelper } from './symbol-helper';
  2 | import { ts, SyntaxKind } from 'ts-simple-ast';
> 3 | import { expect } from 'chai';
    | ^
```

My jest configuration looks like following snippet:

```
"jest": {
"globals": {
  "ts-jest": {
    "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.json",
    "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.(html|svg)$",
    "isolatedModules": true
  }
},
"preset": "jest-preset-angular",
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
  "<rootDir>/setup.jest.ts"
],
"testRunner": "jasmine2",
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)"
],
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$": "jest-preset-angular"
},
"testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx)$",
"resolver": "jest-preset-angular/build/resolvers/ng-jest-resolver.js",
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "ts",
  "tsx",
  "js"
]}
```

How can I exclude the node_folder. The former way seems not working:

```
 "transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules"
],
```

How can I configure jest properly?

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed:

```
"ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
```

was missing before it was a minor version.